# Como puedo obtener el valor de un radioButton en ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: .net, mvc, asp, core

Public
                
            
Deseo recibir el radio seleccionado y guardarlo dentro de mi campo en la base de datos,
el Campo en Db es de tipo varchar..

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow, te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que mejores tus preguntas... Además, te recomiendo que agregues el código que tengas, en donde este el error para que uno pueda trabajar con ello.

Comment: <div class="form-check-inline">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input asp-for="EsEntidadPublica" name="radioopcion" id="p" value="Si" type="radio" class="form-check-input">Publica
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check-inline">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input asp-for="EsEntidadprivada" name="radioopcion" value="Si" id="pr" type="radio" class="form-check-input">Privada
                </label>
            </div>

Comment: Dentro de mi formulario tengo dos input radio, mi problema es que cuando hago el submit, todos los datos me llegan bien, pero el radio seleccionado llega null como si no lo hubieses seleccionado.

Comment: En el modelo el campo que mapea el radio es de tipo string.public string EsEntidadPublica { get; set; }

        public string EsEntidadprivada { get; set; }

Comment: Ese codigo debes agregarlo en tu pregunta, para que sea visto correctamente